# popen vs. KornShell security

Tags: c, shell, unix, ksh, popen

I am writing a C program using some external binaries to achieve a planned goal. I need to run one command which gives me an output, which in turn I need to process, then feed into another program as input. I am using popen, but wonder if that is the same as using a KornShell (ksh) temporary file instead.

**For example:**

```
touch myfile && chmod 700
cat myfile > /tmp/tempfile 
process_file < /tmp/tempfile  && rm /tmp/tempfile
```

Since that creates a temporary file which can be readable by root, would it be the same if one used popen in C, knowing that pipes are also files? Or is it safe to assume that the Operating System (OS) will not allow any other process to read your pipe?

Comment: Don't use 700 permission; you are not creating an executable. Use 600.

Answer (score 1):

You say "that creates a temporary file which can be readable by root", which implies that you are attempting to transfer the data in a way in which the root user cannot read it. That's impossible; in general, the root user has total control of the system, and can thus read any data that is on the system, whether it's in a temporary file or not. Even within a single process, the root user can read the memory of that process.

If you use `popen()`, there will not be an entry for the file on a filesystem; it creates a pipe, which acts like a file, but doesn't actually write that data to disk, instead it just passes it between two programs.

There will be a file descriptor for it; depending on the system, it may be easier or harder to intercept that data, but it will always be possible to do so. For instance, on Linux, you can just look in `/proc/<pid>/fd/` to find all of the open file descriptors and manipulate them (read from or write to them).

Comment: Thanks Brian, the concern is not for a human user with root access to read a file, rather for process separation. I am trying to find out what is the most secure way to write a program which deals with sensitive data. For example, one might suggest shared memory as a better alternative (I am not an experienced programmer, therefore I wouldn't know).

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @user1944224 Creating a pipe (using `popen`) will keep all of the data in memory; it will never write it to disk (unless as swap, but that's true of any data in memory). It will also not create a file on any filesystem for it. So in that sense, it's more secure, as you are less likely to accidentally expose the file (writing files to `/tmp` has a variety of problems if you're not careful). Nothing can protect your data from a program running as root which is trying to extract data from your program; it doesn't matter how you communicate, a privileged process can just read your memory directly.

Comment: Although Linux creates an inode for an anonymous pipe, it is not visible on the file system (unlike a named pipe/fifo).  Anonymous pipes can only be used between related processes (parent-child, siblings, or similar).

Comment: On many systems other than Linux, pipes are going to be harder to read than shared memory; root can attach to shared memory to read it.  On Linux, pipes may still be tricky to intercept; the reads are destructive of the data, so if `root` reads the information, another process won't see it at all.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler While it may be a little less convenient for root to read from a pipe, it's not all that hard. They can just call [`tee`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html) to copy data from the pipe without consuming it. Or they could just attach to your process and trace its syscalls. Or read data from your process's `/proc/$pid/mem`. Or any number of other methods of obtaining the data.